# Rails unable to upload file using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

[image][image]I am following this [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940)

I am trying to upload a file using paperclip gem ..When I try to upload a file i get an error **Method Not Allowed** Thats why my assets table is blank no data is inserting

[asset.rb]

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

   belongs_to :user
    has_attached_file :uploaded_file

    validates_attachment_size :uploaded_file, :less_than => 10.megabytes   
    validates_attachment_presence :uploaded_file


  def file_name 
    uploaded_file_file_name 
end

def file_size 
    uploaded_file_file_size 
end
end
```

[user.rb]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

    has_many :assets



end
```

[assets_controller]

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController

       before_filter :authenticate_user!  #authenticate for users before any methods is called 


      def index 
        @assets = current_user.assets   

      end

      def show 
        @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id]) 
      end

      def new
        @asset = current_user.assets.new
      end

      def create 
        @asset = current_user.assets.new(user_assets) 
        if @asset.save
           flash[:notice] = "Successfully uploaded the file."
        else
           render :action => 'new'
        end

      end

      def edit 
        @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id]) 
      end

      def update 
        @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id]) 

      end

      def destroy 
        @asset = current_user.assets.find(params[:id]) 

      end


    private
        def user_assets
             params.require(:asset).permit(:user_id, :uploaded_file)
        end

    end
    <br>
```

[assets/_form.html.erb]

```
<%= form_for @asset, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %> 
  <%= f.error_messages %> 

    <p> 
        <%= f.label :uploaded_file, "File" %><br /> 
        <%= f.file_field :uploaded_file %> 
      </p> 
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload" %></p> 
<% end %>
```

[assets/new.html.erb]

```
<% title "Upload a file" %> 

<%= render 'form' %> 

<p> 
   <%= link_to "Back", root_url %> 
</p>
```

[3](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940)[migration]

```
class CreateAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assets do |t|
           t.integer :user_id
           t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :assets, :user_id
  end
end
```

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHqeK.png)[migration]

```
class AddAttachmentUploadedFileToAssets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :assets do |t|
        add_column :assets, :uploaded_file_file_name, :string
        add_column :assets, :uploaded_file_content_type, :string
        add_column :assets, :uploaded_file_file_size, :integer
        add_column :assets, :uploaded_file_updated_at, :datetime
    end
  end


end
```

[image: upload using paperclip[![][2]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHqeK.png)

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: i have mention the error  method now allowed only .....

Comment: when I am trying to click on upload button it is saying that only

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or something? I really need to see the context of the error

Comment: ok i am posting over here

Comment: lol okay so you're right. What about a screenshot of the console when you send the request to your model?

Comment: when I am clicking on upload button I am getting this error

Comment: on console everything is showing okay i guess

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a screenshot of your console?

Comment: ok I am posting of console

Comment: POST http://localhost:3001/assets 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: gettint this error on console

Comment: Okay the problem is you've called it `assets` - you need to change this to something else as it's conflicting with Rails

Comment: okay let me try this one

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: yes it worked for me

Comment: that will look weird you should answer it and i will give you point

Comment: Alright, let me write it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the OP was referencing `/assets` which is reserved by Rails as a public path.

The solution would therefore be to change *at least* the routes to be something other than `/assets`; the `Model` can remain but the controller would probably have to change too:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :assets, path: "asset", only: [:new, :create] #-> url.com/asset/new
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you are not the bucket owner but have PutBucketPolicy permissions on the bucket, Amazon S3 returns a 405 Method Not Allowed.
>   (From this [S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTpolicy.html))

Assuming you're using S3 as per the tutorial, perhaps you have not set up your S3 keys properly in your initializer.

Comment: I am not using amazon s3... I am trying to upload to my local machine ....and thats why I am getting that error